# How to disable inertial earth rotation in Qt4.x versions of KDE Marble

Tags: c++, qt, kde-plasma, marble

When I drag and move left mouse, map continues moving after the mouse release. You can deactivate this feature in Qt5 Marble versions by setting:

```
marbleWidget->inputHandler()->setInertialEarthRotationEnabled( false );
```

This function does not exist in older Qt4.x Marble APIs. Is there an equivalent function or way to get the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version are you looking at exactly? We had some refactorings in the input handler code, and the current method `setInertialEarthRotationEnabled(bool)` was called `setKineticScrollingEnabled(bool)` some years ago, see https://github.com/KDE/marble/blob/KDE/4.10/src/lib/MarbleWidgetInputHandler.h.

Comment: Unfortunately we're on KDE/4.8 [GitHub link](https://github.com/KDE/marble/blob/KDE/4.8/src/lib/MarbleWidgetInputHandler.h) and the function did not exist back then. We are now checking if an upgrade of Marble within our application is possible